# navigator.share is undefined

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I want to build the functionality to enable the user to open gmail from my pwa(built using react/redux) and send an email.The [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/navigator-share) looked promising but when I looked up navigator.share in my browser console, it outputs undefined.I am using chrome Version-58.

Answer (score 0):

It enabled by default for Chrome for Android version 61.

If you don't get that version, try Chrome Dev.

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.dev

**Reference**

https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5668769141620736